# How to Fix error related to libicudata.so

Tags: libraries, shared-library

I'm getting following error when invoking a binary file from command line:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried installing following packages, and it didn't solve the problem

```
libicu-dev
libicu48
libicu48-dbg
```

Can you tell me the steps to fix this problem ?

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libicudata.so.55` comes from the `libicu55` [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/wily/amd64/libicu55/filelist) which is only available in the development version of Ubuntu, *wily werewolf*. You can get the `.deb` manually from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/wily/libicu55) but it is not going to work because of the dependency problem. You will have to install those dependencies as well.

To remain on a stable release of Ubuntu (or any other debian system) while grabbing packages from a more recent version, you should use "Pinning" as described in the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).